# Pandas: Select from date in MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have MultiIndex series as

```
date        foo
2006-01-01  1         12931926.310
            3         11084049.460
            5         10812205.359
            7          9031510.239
            9          5324054.903
2007-01-01  1         11086082.624
            3         12028419.560
            5         11957253.031
            7         10643307.061
            9          6034854.915
```

If it weren't a MultiIndex, I could select those with year `2007` through `df.loc['2007']`. How do I do this here? My natural guess was `df.loc['2007', :]`, but that gave my an empty `Series([], name: FINLWT21, dtype: float64)`.

### Ultimate Goal

Ultimatively, I am also interested in replacing all rows for different dates than `2007` with the rows of the year `2007`.

That is, my expected output is

```
date        foo
2006-01-01  1         11086082.624
            3         12028419.560
            5         11957253.031
            7         10643307.061
            9          6034854.915
2007-01-01  1         11086082.624
            3         12028419.560
            5         11957253.031
            7         10643307.061
            9          6034854.915
```

I tried to implement @unutbu's solution, but

```
mySeries.loc[dateIndex.year != 2007] = mySeries.loc[dateIndex.year == 2007]
```

will naturally set the values (due to non-existence on the RHS) to `NaN`. Usually, these issues are fixed by

```
mySeries.loc[dateIndex.year != 2007] = mySeries.loc[dateIndex.year == 2007].values
```

, but given that I have `10` values (and more in my real dataset) on the lefthand side, but only `5` on the right, I get

```
ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value
```

The only alternative that comes to my mind now is to iterate over the first index and then use the previous command for each subgroup, but that doesn't appear to be the most efficient solution.

Comment: What if the series contains a leap date such as `2008-02-29`? How is it to map to a date in `2007`?

Comment: @unutbu it doesn't: the data is either quarterly or annual, in any case, any day is `01`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the Series

```
In [207]: series
Out[212]: 
date        foo
2006-01-01  1      12931926.310
            3      11084049.460
            5      10812205.359
            7       9031510.239
            9       5324054.903
2007-01-01  1      11086082.624
            3      12028419.560
            5      11957253.031
            7      10643307.061
            9       6034854.915
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

you could extract the `date` index with

```
dateindex = series.index.get_level_values('date')
# Ensure the dateindex is a DatetimeIndex (as opposed to a plain Index)
dateindex = pd.DatetimeIndex(dateindex)
```

Now selection of the rows where the year equals 2007 can be done with
a boolean condition:

```
# select rows where year equals 2007
series2007 = series.loc[dateindex.year == 2007]
```

---

If the `foo` values cycle through the same values in the same order for each date, 
then you could replace all the values in the series with those from 2007 with

```
N = len(series)/len(series2007)
series[:] = np.tile(series.loc[dateindex.year == 2007].values, N)
```

An advantage of using `np.tile` and `.values` is that it will generate the desired array of values relatively quickly. A (possible) disadvantage is that this is ignoring the index so it relies on the assumption that the `foo` values cycle through the same values in the same order for each date.

The more robust (but slower) way is to use a join:

```
df = series.reset_index('date')
df2007 = df.loc[dateindex.year==2007]
df = df.join(df2007, rsuffix='_2007')
df = df[['date', 'val_2007']]
df = df.set_index(['date'], append=True)
df = df.swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
```

yields

```
In [304]: df.swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
Out[304]: 
                    val_2007
date       foo              
2006-01-01 1    11086082.624
           3    12028419.560
           5    11957253.031
           7    10643307.061
           9     6034854.915
2007-01-01 1    11086082.624
           3    12028419.560
           5    11957253.031
           7    10643307.061
           9     6034854.915
2008-01-01 1    11086082.624
           3    12028419.560
           5    11957253.031
           7    10643307.061
           9     6034854.915
```

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my ultimate goal. But given your first answer, that is straight forward: `series.loc[dateindex.year != 2007]  = series.loc[dateindex.year == 2007]` should do exactly what I want.

Comment: I think that would assign `NaN`s. Did you mean `series.loc[dateindex.year != 2007] = series.loc[dateindex.year == 2007].values`?

Comment: Yes, I meant exactly that and tried both now - but the latter also raises issue, see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

To select the values from the MultiIndex for the desired year (e.g. 2007), you can use:

```
target_year = 2007
df[[ts.year == target_year for ts in df.index.get_level_values(0)]]
```

If the date index is not in the form of a timestamp, it needs to be converted:

```
df[[pd.Timestamp(ts).year == target_year for ts in df.index.get_level_values(0)]]
```