# Pandas MultiIndex: Difference over time for subgroups

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a data frame with group (`county`), time (here, index) information and then a variable of interest, `emplvl`. I would like to compute, for each group, the difference in `emplvl` for two specific times, say [`'2012-10' - '2005-01'`].

I have seen several approaches to similar questions here, but all of them have some sort of trouble:

- I can use `df['2010-10']` to access data with a specific date, but this approach doesn't work if I have a MultiIndex over `date, county` - and if I didn't have that, how would I find the correspondence efficiently?
- [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29460440/1082349) say to use `series.index.get_level_values('date').year == 2010`, and similar for day. I suppose I could do that, but then how exactly do I do the difference? Do I need to groupby for each county, and then do the time-difference manually? Doesn't appear efficient either.

*Note: I don't have data for every county-date combination, so the solution must be `NaN`-Robust*. Here's some sample data:

```
                  emplvl  county
date                            
2005-01-01  11441.000000    1001
2005-01-01  53733.000000    1003
2005-04-01  57080.000000    1003
2005-04-01  11531.000000    1001
2005-07-01  57612.000000    1003
2005-07-01  11320.000000    1001
2005-10-01  56016.000000    1003
2005-10-01  11516.666667    1001
2012-01-01  58028.666667    1003
2012-01-01  10065.333333    1001
2012-04-01  62307.666667    1003
2012-04-01  10172.666667    1001
2012-07-01  10042.000000    1001
2012-07-01  61926.000000    1003
2012-10-01  59498.666667    1003
2012-10-01  10267.666667    1001
```

#### Expected Output

```
                    difference       county
   59498.666667 - 53733.000000         1003
   10267.666667 - 11441.000000         1001
```

Comment: can you provide a corresponding sample data set and expected output? The data set/frame you have provided can't be used for your task...

Comment: Thanks! What is your expected output?

Comment: so you don't care of index(date) - correct?

Comment: which "two different indices"? if you want to group your data buy part of the date, you would have to explain - how do you want to do that. Your question is not clear

Comment: I substract the value at index `2012-10` minues the value at index `2005-01`. Perhaps I shouldve said "two different index values".

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly:

```
In [81]: df.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [82]: df
Out[82]:
         date        emplvl  county
0  2005-01-01  11441.000000    1001
1  2005-01-01  53733.000000    1003
2  2005-04-01  57080.000000    1003
3  2005-04-01  11531.000000    1001
4  2005-07-01  57612.000000    1003
5  2005-07-01  11320.000000    1001
6  2005-10-01  56016.000000    1003
7  2005-10-01  11516.666667    1001
8  2012-01-01  58028.666667    1003
9  2012-01-01  10065.333333    1001
10 2012-04-01  62307.666667    1003
11 2012-04-01  10172.666667    1001
12 2012-07-01  10042.000000    1001
13 2012-07-01  61926.000000    1003
14 2012-10-01  59498.666667    1003
15 2012-10-01  10267.666667    1001

In [83]: grouped = df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month, df.county]).sum()

In [84]: grouped
Out[84]:
                        emplvl
date date county
2005 1    1001    11441.000000
          1003    53733.000000
     4    1001    11531.000000
          1003    57080.000000
     7    1001    11320.000000
          1003    57612.000000
     10   1001    11516.666667
          1003    56016.000000
2012 1    1001    10065.333333
          1003    58028.666667
     4    1001    10172.666667
          1003    62307.666667
     7    1001    10042.000000
          1003    61926.000000
     10   1001    10267.666667
          1003    59498.666667


In [85]: grouped.ix[(2012, 10)] - grouped.ix[(2005, 1)]
Out[85]:
             emplvl
county
1001   -1173.333333
1003    5765.666667
```

Comment: it will sum up your `emplvl` if you'll have multiple values in one group (year, month, county), otherwise it'll take the corresponding value